# Why does the exit command not exit from nested while loop?

Tags: shell-script

I have the following script. It prints all of first characters to console from passwd, but my expectation was to get only one character and for the program to then terminate.

```
#!/bin/sh 

cat /etc/passwd |
while read -r line
do
    echo ${line} |
        grep -o . |
        while read char
        do
            echo ${char}   
            exit 1       
        done
done
```

Actual output:

```
r
b
d
a
(etc)
```

Expected output:

```
r
```

Comment: Pipes create subprocesses. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359777/bash-exit-doesnt-exit

Answer (score 0):

Most Bourne-like shells, except `zsh` and `ksh` run each part of pipelines in subshells. Assuming you don't use `zsh` or `ksh`, then in your script, the last part of pipiline was run in subshell, so `exit` quit that subshell instead of current shell.

You will get the desire output in `zsh` or `ksh`.

Anyway, those code have many flaws:

- [UUOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat)
- [Using `while` loop to process text](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/38906)
- [Forgetting double quotes variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/38906)

---

If all you want is getting the first character in file:

```
dd bs=1 count=1 if=/etc/passwd 2>/dev/null
```

or with GNU `dd`:

```
dd status=none bs=1 count=1 if=/etc/passwd
```

It only works with ASCII characters. For multi-byte characters:

```
LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 awk '{print substr($0,1,1);exit}'
```

Change `LC_ALL` to what locale your text belong to.

Answer (score 0):

Pipes creates sub-shells. The shell builtin `exit` terminates a shell. Resulting in the unexpected behavior in your case:

```
> exit | exit | echo wow
wow
```

I suggest looking at the **Pipelines** section in `man bash`. Also look at `help exit`.